# extjs application shows blank page in web2py

Tags: javascript, extjs, web2py

I'm trying to combine `web2py` and `Sencha extjs`. So far, I've done the following:

1. install `web2py` and `sencha` (obviously)
2. copy `sencha`'s `sdk` folder (ext-6.0.1) into `web2py`'s static folder
3. create a new `sencha` project within `web2py`'s static folder, using

   ```
   sencha -sdk ./ext6-6.0.1 -classic MyApp ./
   ```

   This created the following folders within `web2py` static:
   [image: folders in static]
4. I copied the content of the `index.html` created by `sencha` and pasted into the `web2py index.html`, where I changed the line

   ```
   <script id="microloader" data-app="bbcdf0cd-c0e2-4208-be64-6dfd8a9f550c" type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>
   ```

   to

   ```
   <script id="microloader" data-app="bbcdf0cd-c0e2-4208-be64-6dfd8a9f550c" type="text/javascript" src="static/bootstrap.js"></script>
   ```

When I start the `web2py` server and visit the application, it shows a **blank page**. Firebug console indicates no error at all. Yet if i visit *`.../static/index.html`* everything works as it should.
I've also tried to include the `sencha index.html` directly, but that didn't work either.
What am I forgetting to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have set your app as the default application in `routes.py`, the URL should include the app name:

```
src="/yourapp/static/bootstrap.js"
```

Actually, you should always use the `URL` helper to construct web2py URLs:

```
src="{{=URL('static', 'bootstrap.js')}}"
```

Note, the `URL` helper will automatically include the name of the current app if you don't specify it as the first argument.

Also, since you will want the Ext JS front end to work with all of your pages, you probably want to copy the relevant code from the Ext JS index.html page into your layout.html, not your /views/default/index.html view (which only applies to the /yourapp/default/index page).

Finally, note that there may be other URLs in the Ext JS files that need to be changed to accommodate web2py's routing.